# A reasonable, modern way to store and retrieve a single piece of information in an iOS app

Tags: ios, ios7

I have done iOS for awhile but never full-time and not for awhile so consider this a "is this a reasonable practice in 2014 type question"

I want to store a single string of information (the host to connect to) for an iPhone app that will reflect different apis to point to (`staging.domain.com`, `domain.com`, or `localhost`). What would be the correct, modern way to do this? I am currently using a plist entry and then

```
NSString *host = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"host"];
```

The information is used in only 4 different places in the app so ideally would would be a static global object or something (like a `rails config.rb`); I don't want anything fancy. Would a global singleton object be better? Or using a `UIApplication delegate`? I'm not using Core Data.

Comment: Check out NSUserDefaults https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @ryancumley Defaults are for a different purpose.

Comment: thx but really? NSUserDefaults - I thought that was the one to clearly not use.

Comment: so not user choice - like a config object that would be different based upon build. like config.rb in rails

Comment: It seems there is some confusion about your question. Now that I read it again, along with the other comments, it seems you are not asking where to store the value, but how to access a value in various places through your app.

Comment: ok - sorry; my fault. I'll try to update the question.

Comment: app delegate is the right choice for  your because its accesible from every where in your application, no need of NSUserDefault because data in bundle applicaiton

Comment: @CoolMonster No, the app delegate should not be used as a catch-all for little bits of info just because you have easy access to it via the `UIApplication sharedApplication`.

Comment: @timpone why not your use macro for this simple string info

Comment: @CoolMonster - y, a macro looks good; sorry for such a basic question - just wanted to be sure I wasn't doing something bad (and I probably would have just left it as the plist call so glad to see the macro soln)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is good, but since you are using it from several places, it is best to not repeat yourself, and make a helper for this.

Several approaches are possible 
1- one would be defining a "plain" helper function,
2- another would be defining a class method in a helper "utility" class. This would centralize the way you access the host string.

Here is an example with a free-standing helper function.

in the `MYUtility.h`:

```
extern NSString *MYHost();
```

In the MYUtility.m

```
NSString *MYHost() {
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"host"];
}
```

At the point of use:

```
NSString *host = MYHost();
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefault` is best way. With `NSUserDefaults` you can save objects from the following class types:

```
NSData
NSString
NSNumber
NSDate
NSArray
NSDictionary
```

Eg. `NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

```
[defaults setObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
[defaults setObject:lastName forKey:@"lastname"];
[defaults setInteger:age forKey:@"age"];
[defaults setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];

[defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults can be helpful, or abused, it comes down to the semantics of your situation.

Reading your question closer, for a simple server path, you can make a .h file that is nothing more than a handful of `static NSString *const nameOfThisServerPath = @"http://google.com";` declarations. No @interface or other class declarations, just those static strings.

import that file to your .pch file, and you'll have access to that server path just like it was a class variable from every class in your app. You could even just declare it in your .pch file if you didn't want to encapsulate it within it's own file.

A pre-proccesor macro in your .pch would do much the same. Pick your poison.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can add the host link directly to macro instead of budle like this

```
#define hostURL @"http://somewere.someone.com";
```

if your want to fetch the data again and again from the bundle means you can define a macro like this

```
#define hostURL [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"host"];
```

Add either of these to your `.pch` file will let to you access through out your application. If you have more configuration like this, just create simple header file and add these stuff to that file and import that header in `.pch` will let to organize all your configuration in single file.